# Markov property extends to all future times

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, conditional-probability

I'm studying Pavliotis' Stochastic Processes and I am having trouble with one of the exercises.

Specifically the first exercise of chapter two is prove that the Markov property in the sense off the immediate future being independent of the past given the present, i.e. $P(X_{n+1} | X_1, \dots, X_n) = P(X_{n+1} | X_n)$ implies that arbitrary futures are independent of the past given the present, i.e. $P(X_{n+m} | X_1, \dots, X_n) = P(X_{n+m} | X_n)$.

Conceptually I imagine a proof using induction along the lines of:
Assume the equality holds for some $m$, then
\begin{gather}
P(X_{n+m+1} | X_1, \dots, X_n) = \int P(X_{n+m+1}, X_{n+m} = x | X_1, \dots, X_n) dx
\\
= \int P(X_{n+m+1} | X_{n+m} = x) P(X_{n+m} = x | X_1, \dots, X_n) dx \\
= \int P(X_{n+m+1} | X_{n+m} = x) P(X_{n+m} = x | X_n) dx \\
= \int P(X_{n+m+1}, X_{n+m} = x | X_n) dx = P(X_{n+m+1} | X_n)
\end{gather}

However, this is based on intuition and my experience non-measure-theoretic probability theory. I cannot justify these steps when I think of $P$ as a measure and $P(X=x)$ meaning $P\{X^{-1}(x)\}$.
In fact I have had trouble finding a definition of conditional probability that is at all helpful. Most authors seem to provide the abstract definition in terms of conditional expectation with respect to $\sigma$-algebra, but I haven't found any resources that show how to work with this definition.

So my question is: how (if it all) are these steps, particularly the first two equalities justified from a measure theoretic perspective?

Comment: Maybe I am being naive.  However For any $m\gt n$, $P(X_m|x_n,..,X_1)=P(X_m|X_n)$ should follow from defining a new Markov process by $Y_{n+1}=X_m$ and $Y_k=X_k$ for $1\le k\le n$.

Comment: Wouldn't you have to prove that $Y_t$ is indeed a Markov process?

Comment: The main problem is having a very precise definition for a Markov process or a Markov chain.  My gut feeling is that your original question might be answered by such a precise definition.

Comment: The definition I've seen everywhere is: a stochastic process on probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$ together with a collection of random variable $\{X_t\}_{t \in \mathbb{N}}$ where $P(X_{n+m} | X_1, \dots, X_n) = P(X_{n+m} | X_n)$.
The only part of that definition that is not 100% precise to me is the conditional probability.

Comment: Why don't you think it is precise?

Comment: I'm not saying it's not. As I mentioned in my question I don't understand it so I am not making a statement on whether or not it is a precise definition, that's what I meant by "not 100% precise to me".

Comment: How does this (or another) definition of a Markov process help though?

Comment: An aside.  The first line of your proof looks weird.

Answer (score 0):

A Markov process $X_t$ is a stochastic process which can be described in terms of a transition operator $T_{s,t}$ where $X_t=T_{s,t}X_s$.  For the particular case of Markov chains, the operator is a matrix.

For your original question, we are given $X_{n+1}=T_{n,n+1}X_n$  Therefore $X_{n+m}=T_{n.m}X_n$ where $T_{n,m}=T_{m-1.m}\times...\times T_{n,n+1}$ is the product of given operators.

Comment: I hope this answers your question.

Comment: I'm sorry this does not answer my question at all. I'm not asking for any proof of the stated property, but about the validity of the argument I gave (assuming the measure-theoretic formulation of probability theory).

Comment: It like your argument is an induction argument?

Comment: I finally understand  what concerned me about your derivation.  General formula $P(A|B)=\int P(A|B=x)f_B(x)dx$, where $f_B(x)$ is pdf.  In the rhs of your first equation you are missing a pdf for $X_{m+n}$ although you put something in on the next line, which may be the pdf.

Comment: I'm trying to argue only in terms of measures without assuming existence of densities.
My intuition does come from pdfs of course, and the first line is supposed to be analogous to $p(X) = \int p(x,y) dy$.

Comment: And yes, it is an induction argument, but I'm trying to understand it at the bare bones level of measures, where I'm fairly certain it should follow from disintegration and the assumed independence. Introducing an operator makes for a nice abstract proof but it's exactly the nitty gritty that I'm interested in.

Comment: It looks like the bare ones argument is correct.  What do you mean by 'disintegration'?